# Issues setting up bash autocomplete for Python3 alias

Tags: command-line, bash, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux, alias

I've got an alias for python3, 'py' - it's set up as you might expect in my .bashrc file.

```
alias py='python3'
complete -F _python py
```

The issue is that complete will only work if I try to complete with the base python command python prior. Here's an example in the terminal log below:

```
~/askubuntodemo: ls                           
main.py

~/askubuntodemo: py -bash: completion: function `_python' not found

~/askubuntodemo: python main.py
hello world

~/askubuntodemo: py main.py
hello world
```

Is there a way I can initialise the autocomplete as soon as I log in as opposed to having to manually initiallise by doing a complete with the main python complete first.

(edit: for error in .bashrc while posting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For autocomplete, I've solved this (with another alias, but modified here for python) by adding the following to `/etc/bash_completion.d/bash_completion`:

```
if [[ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/python3 ]]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/python3 && complete -F _python python py
fi
```

I believe this could also be added to `.bashrc`, but both will be sourced so the result is the same.

Comment: My bad - I miss-typed  while writing the post. I will edit for future reference. I've just added your suggestion to the config file, and everything is working perfectly. Thanks a ton for the help.